# Nextjs override back button of browser

Tags: next.js, next-router

I only have single route and want to control changing of components by executing a function on browser back button press but the browser closes when back button is pressed because of single route, please help me guys .I tried to add popstate event to window object , but still won't work.

```
`export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const [queryClient] = React.useState(() => new QueryClient());
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", handleBackButtonPress);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("popstate", handleBackButtonPress);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleBackButtonPress = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("hiiiii back button pressed");
  };

  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
`
```